# Tkinter: Creating async timer, but both time and tk.after don't work, causing infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, timer, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a timer that updates the Tkinter GUI every second, but neither time nor tk.after are actually delaying the time, causing my program to crash. I'm using this timer to update my widgets in the main thread, while another worker Process runs a test. Here's what I tried (relevant parts only):

```
import time
import threading
from Tkinter import *

class View(Frame):
   def __init__(self, top):
        Frame.__init__(self, top)
        self.top = top
        self.async_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.async_update, args=(self.top,))
        self.async_update_thread.start() 

   def async_update(self, top):
        top.update()
        top.after(1000, self.async_update(top))
        '''
        while True:
           top.update()
           time.sleep(1)
        '''

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
   top = Tk()
   top.geometry("1250x750")
   View(top)
   top.mainloop()
```

This code results in the following error:

```
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

How should I handle this error that seems to ignore my delay settings?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
top.after(1000, self.async_update(top))
```

It is exactly the same as this code:

```
result = self.async_update(top)
top.after(1000, result)
```

See the problem? `after` requires a *callable*. Instead, you are calling the function immediately.

The proper way to call `after` is  like this:

```
top.after(1000, self.async_update, top)
```

Comment: That's a very good point and I can't believe I missed that! However, when calling it the correct way, the same error still occurs. I also wouldn't have had this problem with the time.sleep function. For some reason, there's no delay. Is this because I'm running tkinter functions on a different thread, since tkinter is very bad for multithreading?

Comment: @cl12: if any code in a separate thread tries to interact with a widget, there's a chance the program will crash. All tkinter interaction needs to be on the same thread.